# I am using drupal opigno - did anyone know where I can found user menu template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, drupal-templates

I am using opigno 3, and trying to delete some elements from user menu which it no configurable,
I searched so much in the theme templates but I cant find which one have the user menu code.

I am sure it is hard coded but I cant figure where to find it, is there anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mr.avatar Menu items and order weight are configured in each module individually. You will not find this in DB or template. Take a look on  module.links.menu.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Template of Opingo site header block located at:

```
/modules/contrib/opigno_dashboard/templates/opigno-site-header.html.twig
```

Plugin of this block located:

```
/modules/contrib/opigno_dashboard/src/Plugin/Block/SiteHeaderBlock.php
```